# Foolproof Way To Check For SSL With PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssl

We have a need to check for certain if the server has SSL installed. Every method that we tried does not seem to be fool proof.

Our ultimate goal is if someone types in http://somedomain.com, we can test is the server has SSL and then display https://somedomain.com

We need to be able to do this with PHP and not htaccess since this is a module we are creating. Using file_exists or curl all seems to be some sort of drawback where it might not be turned on.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.
eg.

`if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') {
    header("Location: myurl.com");
    exit();
}`

You should try both if the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is empty and if the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is set to `on`.

Be careful you should place this piece of code at the start of the page, because the redirection is happening with `header()` which only works if no html output is done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you connect to `$hostname:443`?
2. Does `$hostname:443` provide a valid certificate for `$hostname`
3. ???
4. Profit!